# BASH : grep count same word occurrence

Tags: bash, regex, grep

Is it possible to count the maximum number of occurrences of a word in a string using only grep ?

Here is an example of what I want :

```
script.sh "aaaa bbbb ccc bbbb azesd bbbb"
```

would return

```
bbbb 3
```

Thank you

Edit : I found a solution. Thanks

Comment: What did you already try. Are you looking for the answer 'yes' or 'no', or for a solution?

Comment: Can you post the solution you found?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo aaaa bbbb ccc bbbb azesd bbbb | tr " " "
" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n1
```

outputs

```
  3 bbbb
```